# Loops in batch file

Tags: batch-file, ibm-mq

Hi I am trying to use batch file to clear message from queue. I have list of queues in a file. I am able to read a file in batch program and clear the queue. If the file contains more than one queue to be cleared , I am able to store them in an array , But Passing the array element to MQ command is not working. Please advise. New to batch scripting, so the method

Code :

```
 for /f %%G in (file.txt) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set fileName[!count!]=%%~G
    call set n=!count!
)
rem echo !fileName[%count%]!

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
echo !fileName[%%i]!
echo display qlocal(!fileName[%%i]!) | runmqsc %1
)
```

I have setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions in the code , and in the above piece echo statement works properly , It is displaying all contents of the array. but it is not getting passed to display qlocal.

New to stackoverflow , if the posting format is not proper apologies.

Comment: You don't need to use `Call`, just `Set "n=!count!"` will do. That said, you don't need to waste time setting it, you can use `(1,1,%count%)` directly. As a side note be careful, _especially when using a `Call`s and `For`s_, that you don't lose your input arguments, (in this case `%1`). It is often safer to assign arguments to variables early in your code, if those arguments aren't being used early in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo display qlocal(!fileName[%%i]!^) | runmqsc %1
```

The caret `^` "escapes" the `)` so that `cmd` sees it as a standard character and does not pair it with the `(` in `for /L ... do (` which closes the `do` block.